# Nagios check_http - from API XMLSchema

Tags: xml, xmlhttprequest, nagios, xmlschema

I would like to setup the Nagios check  "Check_http" to validate the XMLTAG 
 that the value in the XMLTAG is "Licence Valid"

Link to the API is http://IPADDRESS/webapi/webapi.asmx/HealthCheck

```
<ISAStatus xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://IPADDRESS/WebAPI/">
<DeviceLicence>
<Status>Licence Valid</Status>
</DeviceLicence>
<MultipleARCLicence>
<Status>Missing Licence</Status>
</MultipleARCLicence>
</ISAStatus>
```

Or is there an easier way with another Nagios Check ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Nagios XI, rather than `check_http` you'd get an easier time just using `check_xml.php` like

```bash
[root@nagiosxi ~]# php /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_xml.php -u http://127.0.0.1/HealthCheck -k 'DeviceLicence.Status' -s 'Licence Valid'
OK - Value 'Licence Valid' matched 'Licence Valid'
```

Now, if you're just using the barebones Nagios Core engine, I'd advise you to get ahold of the aforementioned plugin by downloading the correspondent [wizard package](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagiosxi/wizards/xi58/xml.zip) — you can find and extract `check_xml.php` at *`xml/plugins`*.

Comment: It is working Perfectly :o)
Thanks a lot @Rfroes87